# Uncaught Error: Module name "functions" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])

Tags: typescript, asp.net-core

I been trying to get TypeScript to work on my ASP.NET Core project to no avail.

I tried a simple one file that displays an alert when page loads and that worked.

Next I wanted to try and start converting some JS into TypeScript manually to get the gist of how typescript works. I have created the following 3 ts files

index.js

```js
import { Functions } from "./functions";
import { SyncResult } from "./indexInterfaces";

const functions = new Functions();
let newEvents = -1;

setInterval(() => {

    const Result: SyncResult = functions.Get('/get-updates') as SyncResult;
    
    if (newEvents < 0) {
        newEvents = Result.newEvents;
        return;
    }
    
    if (newEvents < Result.newEvents) {
        newEvents = Result.newEvents;
    }

}, 5000);
```

IndexInterfaces.ts

```js
interface SyncResult {
    newEvents: number;
}

export { SyncResult }
```

functions.ts

```js
interface HttpJsonResult {

    statusCode: number;
    statusMessage: string;

}

export class Functions {

    public Get(url: string): object {

        fetch(url).then(async response => {

            const res: HttpJsonResult = await response.json();

            if (res.statusCode === 200) {
                return JSON.parse(res.statusMessage);
            }

        });

        return null;
    };

    public Post(url: string, data: object): object {

        const oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

        oReq.open("POST", url, true);
        oReq.onload = () => {
            if (oReq.status === 200) {
                const res: HttpJsonResult = JSON.parse(oReq.responseText);

                if (res.statusCode === 200) {
                    return JSON.parse(res.statusMessage);
                }
            }
        };

        oReq.send(data as XMLHttpRequestBodyInit);

        return null;
    }

}
```

Lastly, my tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "wwwroot/js"
  },
  "include": [
    "scripts/**/*"
  ]
}
```

Problem 1: I tried merging all 3 files into a single output file but this always results in some weird errors,

Problem 2:
Added all 3 output script into the layout (before /body tag)

```html
<script src="~/js/functions.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
<script src="~/js/indexInterfaces.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
<script src="~/js/index.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
```

when loading the page, I get this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined,
I found on a separate stack to add require.js, and I proceeded to downloading it and adding a reference to it.

Now I am getting another error: Uncaught Error: Module name "functions" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])

Anyone can shed some light on this matter as I am losing all hopes that I will get typescript working on my project?

EDIT:
all.js

```js
var __awaiter = (this && this.__awaiter) || function (thisArg, _arguments, P, generator) {
    function adopt(value) { return value instanceof P ? value : new P(function (resolve) { resolve(value); }); }
    return new (P || (P = Promise))(function (resolve, reject) {
        function fulfilled(value) { try { step(generator.next(value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
        function rejected(value) { try { step(generator["throw"](value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
        function step(result) { result.done ? resolve(result.value) : adopt(result.value).then(fulfilled, rejected); }
        step((generator = generator.apply(thisArg, _arguments || [])).next());
    });
};
var __generator = (this && this.__generator) || function (thisArg, body) {
    var _ = { label: 0, sent: function() { if (t[0] & 1) throw t[1]; return t[1]; }, trys: [], ops: [] }, f, y, t, g;
    return g = { next: verb(0), "throw": verb(1), "return": verb(2) }, typeof Symbol === "function" && (g[Symbol.iterator] = function() { return this; }), g;
    function verb(n) { return function (v) { return step([n, v]); }; }
    function step(op) {
        if (f) throw new TypeError("Generator is already executing.");
        while (_) try {
            if (f = 1, y && (t = op[0] & 2 ? y["return"] : op[0] ? y["throw"] || ((t = y["return"]) && t.call(y), 0) : y.next) && !(t = t.call(y, op[1])).done) return t;
            if (y = 0, t) op = [op[0] & 2, t.value];
            switch (op[0]) {
                case 0: case 1: t = op; break;
                case 4: _.label++; return { value: op[1], done: false };
                case 5: _.label++; y = op[1]; op = [0]; continue;
                case 7: op = _.ops.pop(); _.trys.pop(); continue;
                default:
                    if (!(t = _.trys, t = t.length > 0 && t[t.length - 1]) && (op[0] === 6 || op[0] === 2)) { _ = 0; continue; }
                    if (op[0] === 3 && (!t || (op[1] > t[0] && op[1] < t[3]))) { _.label = op[1]; break; }
                    if (op[0] === 6 && _.label < t[1]) { _.label = t[1]; t = op; break; }
                    if (t && _.label < t[2]) { _.label = t[2]; _.ops.push(op); break; }
                    if (t[2]) _.ops.pop();
                    _.trys.pop(); continue;
            }
            op = body.call(thisArg, _);
        } catch (e) { op = [6, e]; y = 0; } finally { f = t = 0; }
        if (op[0] & 5) throw op[1]; return { value: op[0] ? op[1] : void 0, done: true };
    }
};
define("functions", ["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    exports.Functions = void 0;
    var Functions = (function () {
        function Functions() {
        }
        Functions.prototype.Get = function (url) {
            var _this = this;
            fetch(url).then(function (response) { return __awaiter(_this, void 0, void 0, function () {
                var res;
                return __generator(this, function (_a) {
                    switch (_a.label) {
                        case 0: return [4, response.json()];
                        case 1:
                            res = _a.sent();
                            if (res.statusCode === 200) {
                                return [2, JSON.parse(res.statusMessage)];
                            }
                            return [2];
                    }
                });
            }); });
            return null;
        };
        ;
        Functions.prototype.Post = function (url, data) {
            var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
            oReq.open("POST", url, true);
            oReq.onload = function () {
                if (oReq.status === 200) {
                    var res = JSON.parse(oReq.responseText);
                    if (res.statusCode === 200) {
                        return JSON.parse(res.statusMessage);
                    }
                }
            };
            oReq.send(data);
            return null;
        };
        return Functions;
    }());
    exports.Functions = Functions;
});
define("indexInterfaces", ["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
});
define("index", ["require", "exports", "functions"], function (require, exports, functions_1) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    var functions = new functions_1.Functions();
    var newEvents = -1;
    setInterval(function () {
        var Result = functions.Get('/get-updates');
        if (newEvents < 0) {
            newEvents = Result.newEvents;
            return;
        }
        if (newEvents < Result.newEvents) {
            newEvents = Result.newEvents;
        }
    }, 5000);
});
//# sourceMappingURL=all.js.map
```

Comment: `Problem 1: I tried merging all 3 files into a single output file but this always results in some weird errors,` . Could you paste the errors you see in your question? Maybe that's the root of the problem.

Comment: I just updated the config, added in "module": "AMD", and change outDir to "outFile": "wwwroot/js/all.js". The result 0 errors, in the website, nothing is working, I have edited the questions with the "all.js" result.

Answer (score -2):

This is because `required()` does not exist in the client-side JavaScript.

I would recommend you use the `<script>` tag in order to import modules into your project.

Comment: did you read the question? or just the title?